# Multiplying values in a column of data frame based on the numbers found in other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame in the form shown below:

```
payment <- c("Annual", "Monthly","Monthly","Monthly","Quarterly", "Semi Annual")
number_pay <- c(7,81,85,79,16,10)
df <- data.frame(payment, number_pay)

      payment number_pay
1      Annual          7
2     Monthly         81
3     Monthly         85
4     Monthly         79
5   Quarterly         16
6 Semi Annual         10
```

What I want to do is to creat a new column and change all numbers to Monthly number, so for example for the first row, we should have 7*12=84 Month as annual payment means 12-month payment. How can I do this? I was thinking about using `ifelse`; however, this solution doesn't look to be efficient:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(total=ifelse(df$Payment=="Annual", number_pay*12,ifelse(df$Payment=="Quarterly",number_pay*3,)))
```

so basically `ifelse` inside `ifelse`. IS there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the conditions with `case_when` which is cleaner than multiple multiple ifelse statement.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(number_pay = case_when(payment == 'Annual' ~number_pay * 12, 
                                payment == 'Quarterly'~ number_pay * 3, 
                                payment == 'Semi Annual' ~number_pay * 6, 
                                TRUE ~ number_pay))

#      payment number_pay
#1      Annual         84
#2     Monthly         81
#3     Monthly         85
#4     Monthly         79
#5   Quarterly         48
#6 Semi Annual         60
```